# System is not Booting after graphics driver installation

Tags: boot

Last night, I have updated graphics driver. After the installation, system automatically restarted. After that OS is not loading. Only Black screen is coming after Elementary logo. What should i do now.? Do i need to reinstall the OS again?

Note: I am using Elementary Loki OS.

Please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to boot to the black screen and then press Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or F2-F6, I think).

Then, you can log in in a console mode and try to remove or reinstall graphics driver. Or you can try to run `sudo startx` which should tell you where is the problem.

I did this process in Freya when my nVidia driver stopped working with Bumblebee. :-D

Hope that helps.